# vim 9.1 Copy and pasted content is enclosed in bracket Control chars (200~ and 201~)

Tags: vim

I have a .vimrc working well with vim 8 and using the same .vimrc after upgrade to 9.1
Now, in the vim editor whenever I paste any content from clipboard, editor is prefixing and sufficing chars. Example: I copy "namespace" and paste into the vim in the insert mode. I see below content inserted

```
200~namespace201~
```

Comment: You probably have `TERM` set wrong.  What terminal emulator are you using (and are you using something like screen or tmux), and what does `echo $TERM` say at the shell?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is described in help page :help xterm-bracketed-paste
When I disable bracketed paste by putting below in .vimrc:, copy and paste works normal.

```
set t_BE=
```